jupyter notebook removes left blank space of matplotlib
The following code should display "ax" offset to the right (overlapping "ax1") with a padding on the left (where it was originally)
# Implementation of matplotlib function 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm 

Z = np.random.rand(6, 30) 

fig, (ax, ax1) = plt.subplots(1, 2) 

ax.pcolor(Z) 
ax1.pcolor(Z) 

chartBox = ax.get_position() 
ax.set_position([chartBox.x0 + chartBox.width / 2,
                chartBox.y0, 
                chartBox.width, 
                chartBox.height]) 

ax.set_title("Original Window") 
ax1.set_title("Modified Window")

plt.show()

However in a jupyter notebook (tested on vscode and on colab) the left blank space is cut off, but when running the script in a .py file, it displays it correctly. How can I address this issue?
Both tested on a Python 3.12 version in vscode (jupyterlab==4.1.6) and in terminal with matplotlib==3.8.4. Changing plt.show() by plt.savefig() produces the left blank space (even within notebook) I suspect the rendering from the notebook to be at fault but I do not know the exact setting.
Here is what the Jupyter Notebook displays:
Here is what the same code running in a .py script file displays:
Context
I was iterating through some data and wanted to display multiple plots 2 by 2, on odd pairing I wanted to display the single plot centered and turned off the second empty plot. The idea was to use .subplots(nrows=1,ncols=2) (because I had no other idea) and offset the first plot to the right using ax.set_position(). As it turned out it did not work.

"but when running the script in a .py file, it displays it correctly. " That may be the case; however, you aren't saying what version of Python and the involved packages are being used in the case you are running it as a script vs. in Jupyter. The environments are probably different and would help get at your issue. When I run it in Jupyter and then as a script, with the same Python, where I save a file using plt.savefig("test_fig.png") instead of plt.show(), I see the same thing. Namely the 'Modified Window' axis moved over to the left so it overlaps the 'Original Window'....

 at about the point of the 20 value along the 'Original Window' subplot. The 'Original Window' plot stays stuck to the left border no matter if I include the ax.set_position() part or not. As for "The idea was to use .subplots(nrows=1,ncols=2) (because I had no other idea) and offset the first plot to the right using ax.set_position(). ": This is the very definition of an XY problem that you have set up. You may be on the right path; however, what are you actually trying to solve here. The issue you posted about up until the penultimate sentence? Or ...

 what you state was your original goal? For now, you can just clarify in the comments so we are addressing the right thing. I honestly don't know at this point if you were on the right track or not with the approach you are trying. But if the real goal is 'The idea' then I won't endeavor to adhere best to what you have and not consider other approaches.

It is true that I want to do X (have a centered plot horizontally) rather than do Y (have the left blank space not cut off by jupyter notebook), however after short googling I haven't found anyone addressing Y, and I thought that I had so much frustration on attempting Y that it was worth hearing the community on that point, because I assumed that someone in the foreseeable future would stumble upon Y and would find this helpful.

@Wayne I have added some information, but "The 'Original Window' plot stays stuck to the left border no matter if I include the ax.set_position() part or not." do you have this issue even when running the .py file?

Yes, when I run it as Python it stays to the left, too. However, I'm 100% sure both are using the same Python and packages in my system. I'm not convinced you are, given that you are seeing different results. Or maybe it is due to differing backend that you have on your system from Python on command line vs. in Jupyter? (You don't actually say what backend you are seeing it in when you run as a Python script.) I'm only letting it save a plot figure in my case because there is no other choice for graphical backend where I am working in the cloud presently.

The backend for the GUI is TkAgg, and the backend for savefig() is the default (that is agg as per the documentation). On my side, both show the blank space on the left (even when calling plt.savefig() from the notebook). So it is very strange you have a different behaviour

"even when calling plt.savefig() from the notebook" Oh, so if I understand correctly, that seems to rule out my suggestion it is different versions. So when you run the code, you see it adhere to the left side in the notebook output, but with plt.savefig() used in the same notebook it adds the padding?

Yes exactly, on all instances there is a padding, aside from when using plt.show() within the notebook where it adheres to the left side of the window. I do not quite understand why you do not have a padding even when calling plt.savefig(). Because I would assume it's a problem with how jupyter notebook renders matplotlib, but your case suggests me it may be something else.

I got a good lead now on the padding not showing.  I posted an answer since it is rather complex and needs code. Plus, I am looking at what I get from plt.savefig() and there is padding to the left of the 'Original Window'. Concerning your last comment part: " I do not quite understand why you do not have a padding even when calling plt.savefig()" I hadn't seen your updated post back then and understood it was cutting off the padding. I do see padding. In my original two posts I was focused on the movement of the two plots and not realized the padding was what you wanted, too. Sorry.

Hopefully this is what you needed to accomplish your actual goal. You may want to check here just to consider other ways to control layout besides subplot. Plus, there is here, here, and here.

These days if you don't specify anything, then %matplotlib inline is the default backend. And the inline default for bbox_inches these days is tight. I'll come back to this in a minute. And so one option, is to make it not inline. If you go here and click on an 'launch binder' badge (the ones at the bottom allow you to choose the specific Jupyter flavor), you'll get a session where ipympl is installed with modern Jupyter flavors. So you can add %matplotlib ipympl as the first line to the top of you code that you'll next paste in the new cell, & run that and see now the padding is there. (If you don't have ipympl already installed, you'll need to install it first and properly refresh/restart things to use it as the backend. Some say refreshing the browser page is enough; however, I would suggest restarting everything [browser, Jupyter, & your machine] if you can as it adds a lot of abilities in many layers of your tech.)
You can verify that did it by restarting the kernel and adding # in front of %matplotlib ipympl to comment that first line out and re-run the code. It should be back to the inline mode with bbox_inches as tight so the left-most plot is adhering to the left border.
Alternatively you can use configuring of the inline backed to disable bbox_inches='tight'
Since with the inline setting bbox_inches is defaulting as tight, you can continue to use inline backend; however, configure it to not be set to tight.
So in your notebook make a new cell and run the following:
%config InlineBackend.print_figure_kwargs = {'bbox_inches':None}`

Once that is run, try your original code block as-is and you should now see the padding.
Attribution:
Based on the comments and the bottom of that answer there, too where it specifically mentions the 'inline backend' and this answer here to 'How to disable bbox_inches='tight' when working with matplotlib inline in ipython notebook'

%matplotlib ipympl requires to pip install ipympl, but plt.show() returns a javascript error where is written "Error: No version of module jupyter-matplotlib is registered". It requested to download some package. And the stacktrace shows links along the line of *.vscode-resource.vscode-cdn.net. So I believe the issue is with vscode not finding third-party widget. It does work in colab (though you need to add from google.colab import output; output.enable_custom_widget_manager() . Alternatively your 2nd approach works on both colab and vscode. You're awesome!

Yes, I have updated to mention if you don't have it, you need to install it. I do mention where I sent you has it installed. I don't see that error though and so I don't think you refreshed things adequately yet after installation. What you are encountering sounds like my exchange from this point in some related comments and forward. You'll see refreshing / restarting was the tick. I think you are hitting that.

yes indeed, I had to restart vscode, or maybe it was some internet issues.

I don't think it was the internet. There's a lot that ipympl adds and so the updates in settings and changes needs to be fully propagated. I tried clarifying this in the answer, too. The configuring bbox_inches is easier; however, knowing about ipympl will help more people in modern Jupyter use these days considering late JupyterLab 3 and above and Jupyter Notebook 7+ need it for a lot of things now.
